# Azure Codespaces - how to test?

Tags: azure, codespaces

I set up an azure codespace and I can test a node.js through the terminal, but if I want to hit this remotely from a browser, how do I do that? Do I need to deploy it somewhere?

Here's what I see in codespaces:

[image]

Comment: Azure Codespace has been deprecated in favor of GitHub Cotespaces.